# Use of sitemaps

Tags: seo, sitemap

I've recently been involved in the redevelopment of a website (a search engine for health professionals: http://www.tripdatabase.com), and one of the goals was to make it more search engine "friendly", not through any black magic, but through better xhtml compliance, more keyword-rich urls, and a comprehensive sitemap (>500k documents).

Unfortunately, shortly after launching the new version of the site in October 2009, we saw site visits (primarily via organic searches from Google) drop substantially to 30% of their former glory, which wasn't the intention :)

We've brought in a number of SEO experts to help, but none have been able to satisfactorily explain the immediate drop in traffic, and we've heard conflicting advice on various aspects, which I'm hoping someone can help us with.

My question are thus:

1. do pages present in sitemaps *also* need to be spiderable from other pages? We had thought the point of a sitemap was specifically to help spiders get to content *not* already "visible". But now we're getting the advice to make sure every page is also linked to from another page. Which prompts the question... why bother with sitemaps?
2. some months on, and only 1% of the sitemap (well-formatted, according to webmaster tools) seems to have been spidered - is this usual?

Thanks in advance,

Phil Murphy

Answer (score 0):

The XML sitemap helps search engine spider to indexing of all web pages of your site.
The sitemap is very usefull if you publish frequently many pages, but does not replace the correct system of linking of the site: all documents must be linke from an other related page.

Your site is very large, you must attention at the number of URLs published in the  Sitemap because there are the limit of 50.000 URLs for each XML file.

The full documentation is available at [Sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org)

Answer (score 0):

**re: do pages present in sitemaps also need to be spiderable from other pages?** 
Yes, in fact this should be one of the first things you do. Make your website more usable to users before the search engines and the search engines will love you for it. Heavy internal linking between pages is a must first step. Most of the time you can do this with internal sitemap pages or category pages ect..

**re: why bother with sitemaps?**
Yes!, Site map help you set priorities for certain content on your site (like homepage), Tell the search engines what to look at more often. NOTE: Do not set all your pages with the highest priority, it confuses Google and doesn't help you.

**re: some months on, and only 1% of the sitemap seems to have been spidered - is this usual?**
YES!, I have a webpage with 100k+ pages. Google has never indexed them all in a single month, it takes small chunks of about 20k at a time each month. If you use the priority settings property you can tell the spider what pages they should re index each visit.

As *[Rinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206764/rinzi)* mentioned more documentation is available at [Sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try build more backlinks and "trust" (links from quality sources)

May help speed indexing further :)